# how to pass a large string from a delphi dll to a php extension

Tags: php, delphi

I have written a php extension in Visual Studio Express for PHP 7.2 NTS for Windows 7 (all 64-bit). I am using it to access a 3rd party .dll written in C++ and it is working fine.

Now I want it to access a .dll that I am writing in Delphi XE6. The function in the .dll returns a string as a PAnsiChar. It is actually a base64 encoded jpeg image, so can be quite large. I chose to send it as base64 encoded string because I can't see any way of passing an image or array of bytes from the extension back to PHP.

My Delphi code is:

```
function dem_get_map_img(imgdata: PAnsiChar): int32; stdcall;
var
  base64str: ansistring;
begin
   base64str := 'test return value';   // the actual image data will go here
   imgdata := PAnsiChar(base64str);
   Result := 27;                       // some meaningful value will be used later 
end;
```

My PHP extension code is:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(dem_get_map_img)
{
    hGetProcIDDelphiDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("delphiDLL.dll"));
    if (!hGetProcIDDelphiDLL) RETURN_STRING("dll not loaded");

    int rc;
    char imgdata[AS_MAXCH];

    if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 0) RETURN_STRING("wrong param count loaded");

    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDelphiDLL), "dem_get_map_img");
    if (!lpfnGetProcessID) RETURN_STRING("function not found");

    typedef int32(__stdcall * pICFUNC)(char *imgdata);

    pICFUNC dem_get_map_img;
    dem_get_map_img = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);

    rc = dem_get_map_img(imgdata);

    FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDelphiDLL);

    array_init(return_value);
    add_assoc_long(return_value, "retflag", rc);
    add_assoc_string(return_value, "imgdata", imgdata);
}
```

My PHP code is:

```
$outval = dem_get_map_img();
var_dump($outval);
```

which gives me:

```
array(2) {
  ["retflag"]=>
  int(27)
  ["imgdata"]=>
  string(4) "�$�"
}
```

Not what I was hoping for.

Firstly, I have noticed that AS_MAXCH will apparently only allow me 255 characters, which is going to be a problem (help?) but shouldn't be the problem so far.

I have read various similar questions and assume that deallocated memory may be the problem, but so far I have been unable to figure out what to do about it.

I have seen people recommend using CoTaskMemAlloc, but how do I do that in Delphi?

What I really need to do is pass a Jpeg image from my Delphi dll to the PHP extension and into my PHP code, so if there is a better way to do that then I am open to suggestions. My knowledge of C/C++ and PHP extensions is quite limited (you already knew that didn't you).

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

How stupid can you get (.. can I get)?

I just realised what I was doing wrong in the Delphi function.

Revised Delphi function:

```
function dem_get_map_img(imgdata: PAnsiChar): int32; stdcall;
var
  base64str: ansistring;
begin
   base64str:= 'test return value';
   StrPCopy(imgdata, base64str);
   Result := 27;
end;
```

Fill the PAnsiChar, don't create a new one!

I am still curious if anyone has a better suggestion for passing an image or large block of data to PHP though.

UPDATE 2:

Well, with many thanks to David Heffernan for pointing me in the right direction, I think I have it.

I split the Delphi function so that I now have one function that prepares the string and returns the size,

```
Result := length(MapImage) * sizeof(ansichar) + 1;
```

and another one that returns the actual string data as before.

So now I call the first function to prepare the data and use the returned data size to allocate the memory before calling the second function.

My new extension code is:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(dem_get_map_img)
{
    hGetProcIDDelphiDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("delphiDLL.dll"));
    if (!hGetProcIDDelphiDLL) RETURN_STRING("not loaded");

    long rc, imgsize;
    char * imgdata;

    if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 0) RETURN_STRING("wrong param count loaded");

    FARPROC lpfnGetPrepID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDelphiDLL), "dem_prepare_map_img");
    if (!lpfnGetPrepID) RETURN_STRING("prepare function not found");

    typedef int32(__stdcall * pICprep)(long wid, long hei);
    pICprep dem_prepare_map_img;
    dem_prepare_map_img = pICprep(lpfnGetPrepID);

    imgsize = dem_prepare_map_img(900, 450);

    imgdata = (char*)malloc(imgsize);

    FARPROC lpfnGetGetID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDelphiDLL), "dem_get_map_img");
    if (!lpfnGetGetID) RETURN_STRING("get function not found");

    typedef int32(__stdcall * pICget)(char *imgdata);
    pICget dem_get_map_img;
    dem_get_map_img = pICget(lpfnGetGetID);

    rc = dem_get_map_img(imgdata);

    FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDelphiDLL);

    array_init(return_value);
    add_assoc_long(return_value, "retflag", rc);
    add_assoc_long(return_value, "imgsize", imgsize);
    add_assoc_string(return_value, "imgdata", imgdata);

    free(imgdata);
}
```

And I have a nice map on my web page!

My only real concern now is that *free(imgdata)* is being reached. As I understand it the extension function only returns *return_value* at the end of the function, not immediately as with *RETURN_STRING()*.

Comment: If your knowledge is as limited as you say then his can't be solved in a question here. You don't yet have the skills to solve the problem and we can't do it for you. It's time for you to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure, but first thing that came to my mind is that types incompatible. Maybe you should try PWideChar or something else?

Comment: @Alex Guessing is not likely to help. Your guess is quite wrong.

Comment: Oh, there is no `var` in the `dem_get_map_img(imgdata: PAnsiChar)`

Comment: @AlexSlipknot: A var would be wrong. It's not helpful to randomly grab at straws here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have just had an epiphany and updated my question.

Comment: You are nearly there. You'll need to use heap allocated memory.

Comment: So I need to allocate enough memory in the extension, populate it in Delphi, then free it again in the extension? I'll look into that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem with that is that you might not know how much to allocate so you may need to ask the Delphi code. Alternatively you could allocate in the Delphi code and export a deallocator also. Or allocate using a shared heap. That's the CoTaskMemAlloc idea. That let's you deallocate from the other module. Other shared heap APIs include default process heap, HeapAlloc or LocalAlloc.

Comment: I went with the first option and asked the Delphi code. I have updated my question. Many thanks for the help.